# Very simple d3js example not working

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to start with d3 but have bad exp. :) 
I can't make a simple example run localy. I'm runing it under chrome with webstorm local server;

```
http://localhost:63342/svg-tests/index.html
```

There are no errors but no red circles are drawen. And "console.log(d);" is not fired;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/d3.v3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <script>
        var dataSet = [10, 20, 30, 40];
        var svg = d3.select('svg');
        var circle = svg.selectAll('circle')
                .data(dataSet)
                .enter()
                .append('circle')
                .attr({
                    r: function(d){ console.log(d); return d },
                    cx: 10,
                    cy: 10,
                    fill: 'red'
                });
    </script>

    <svg></svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help!?

Comment: Try defining the `<svg>` element before the script.

Comment: that's it!
Add it as an answer so i can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define the `<svg>` element before the script as it relies on it:

```
<svg></svg>

<script>
...
</script>
```